# How does PokeCord do the green bar at the side?

Tags: discord

I am trying to write a discord bot, and i  am curious on how to make the green bar that pokecord and some other bots have.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpVt2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This called embed.
In discord.py you can read about it in [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed).
In discord.js you can read about it and see some examples [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html).